# ADT Troubleshooting

Tags: android, adt, development-environment

Can anyone help me in this, I get this error each time I install Android's ADT Plugin.Initially, I thought Anti-Virus has locked the file then I thought may be the file is open somewhere else but no such case was seen. I've done deleting C:\User_Name.Android folder re-downloading and re-extracting adt from scratch but still I get this error, what should I do?!

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=56829C722C837939!11147&authkey=!AColJeNefGh2lvI&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Answer (score 0):

Try to run as admin and In my opinion every time before you want to install something new, make a copy of \\tools dir in the \\ path, and then, upgrade or install something by excecuting android.bat in the copied tools folder.

Steps:-

1. make a copy of the tools directory and call this new directory tools2.(Go in to your main hard drive, program x86 folder and open android-sdk-windows inside of that folder.(Example: C:Program Files (x86)android-sdk-windows). Copy and paste the tools-folder)
2. DO NOT USE 'SDK Setup.exe'.
3. Instead open up a cmd.exe window and run the following from this new tools2 directory (obviously the full path on your local machine will be different):
   J:\android-sdk-windows>tools2\android.bat update sdk

Basically, as noted before in this thread, 'SDK Setup.exe' invokes tools\android.bat, which makes it impossible for it to rename the tools directory thereafter.

If you have ay doubts refer this link:-http://www.olaflindstrom.se/folder-failed-to-be-renamed-or-moved-when-updating-android-sdk/

Comment: Thanks, Sir! It was fixed. :)